# Why does my terminal only print some Unicode characters correctly?

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I'm having problems printing some Unicode characters. This is the content of the script to be executed:

```
print('Μ Σ ®   ❤️    ')
```

When I execute the command via the Bash shell on Ubuntu running on Windows 10, I get the following results:

```
.../...$ python3 main.py
Μ Σ ® ⍰ ⍰  ⍰  ⍰⍰⍰ ⍰ ⍰ ⍰ ⍰
```

Why are some of the Characters printed correctly and the emoticons not? Whats peculiar is that if I copy and paste the output into a texteditor that supports UTF-8 the emoticons are displayed correctly. Where do I go wrong?

As one can see, UTF-8 is activated:

```
.../... $ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8 
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"                                                                                                      LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

This is the bash version I'm using:

```
.../...$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

This is the version of Ubuntu:

```
.../... $ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: Your terminal isn't using fonts that support all those characters.

Comment: @Shawn thats probably it, makes sense.

Comment: Site note: given how you used "bash" in this post, I think you may be confused about the difference between terminals and shells. Bash isn't isn't involved in how those characters are being displayed. See [What is the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/506510)

Comment: @Brian thanks for mentioning it. I was assuming that the problem could have something to do with character encodings configured in the shell. However, it was a terminal problem, really.

Comment: So, which font in which version are you using? [Unifont 13.0.06](http://unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html) is pretty impressive.